# MySQL server won't start - ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, homebrew

So I have a newer macOS - macOS Mojave 10.14.1. The mysql version I have installed is 5.6 - and I unfortunately cannot upgrade (trying to run our company app, and our files syntax is stuck in 5.6 and won't run in 5.7). I installed using homebrew.

When I run mysql.server start - I get the following error:

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file 
(/usr/local/var/mysql/Cecilles-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

I read up a lot that this is a permissions issue, so I went and made sure that user is set to mysql and not root or me.

```
➜  support-files ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   8 _mysql  staff    256 Nov  8 13:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 _mysql  staff    608 Nov  9 09:44 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   1153 Sep 10 03:23 binary-configure
-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  staff    773 Sep 10 03:23 magic
-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  staff   1105 Nov  8 13:28 my-default.cnf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff    946 Nov  8 13:11 mysql-log-rotate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff  10678 Nov  8 13:11 mysql.server
-rwxr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   1061 Nov  8 13:11 mysqld_multi.server
```

Ran which to see if mysql.server is just a symlink - it was.

```
➜  support-files which mysql.server
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysql.server
```

So I go there to change any necessary permissions.

```
➜  bin ls -la
total 253368
drwxr-xr-x  46 _mysql  staff      1472 Nov  8 13:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 _mysql  staff       608 Nov  9 09:44 ..
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3185296 Nov  8 13:11 innochecksum
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      1569 Nov  8 13:11 msql2mysql
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3180344 Nov  8 13:11 my_print_defaults
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3425124 Nov  8 13:11 myisam_ftdump
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3519928 Nov  8 13:11 myisamchk
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3402280 Sep 10 03:23 myisamlog
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3443204 Nov  8 13:11 myisampack
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3470344 Nov  8 13:11 mysql
lrwxr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff        29 Sep 10 03:23 mysql.server ->         
../support-files/mysql.server
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3761480 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_client_test
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff  11384760 Nov  8 13:11     
mysql_client_test_embedded
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      6556 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_config
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3374832 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_config_editor
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      4299 Sep 10 03:23     
mysql_convert_table_format
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff  11080428 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_embedded
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      3374 Sep 10 03:23 mysql_find_rows
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      1331 Sep 10 03:23 
mysql_fix_extensions
lrwxr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff        27 Sep 10 03:23 mysql_install_db ->     
../scripts/mysql_install_db
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3189504 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_plugin
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff     10106 Sep 10 03:23 
mysql_secure_installation
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff     17550 Sep 10 03:23 mysql_setpermission
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3147136 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3484512 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_upgrade
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3180128 Nov  8 13:11 mysql_waitpid
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      3942 Sep 10 03:23 mysql_zap
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3378320 Nov  8 13:11 mysqladmin
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3547660 Nov  8 13:11 mysqlbinlog
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff     10928 Nov  8 13:11 mysqlbug
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3373696 Nov  8 13:11 mysqlcheck
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff  11766608 Nov  8 13:11 mysqld
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff     27015 Nov  8 13:11 mysqld_multi
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff     27430 Nov  8 13:11 mysqld_safe
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3435992 Nov  8 13:11 mysqldump
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff      7424 Sep 10 03:23 mysqldumpslow
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff     34938 Sep 10 03:23 mysqlhotcopy
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3370296 Nov  8 13:11 mysqlimport
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3368808 Nov  8 13:11 mysqlshow
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3385220 Nov  8 13:11 mysqlslap
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3618408 Nov  8 13:11 mysqltest
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff  11203720 Nov  8 13:11 mysqltest_embedded
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3284632 Nov  8 13:11 perror
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3157072 Sep 10 03:23 replace
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3187036 Nov  8 13:11 resolve_stack_dump
-r-xr-xr-x   1 _mysql  staff   3180348 Nov  8 13:11 resolveip
```

I run mysql.server start and still no dice. I'm pretty sure the PID file isn't being created due to a permissions issue, but at this point, I'm not quite sure what else I have to change permissions/owner on.

Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `brew services rstart mysql@5.6`?

Comment: Hi @CSalazar i think your question has more chances to get answered at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: Thanks! @R.Sierra